# RequestMapping URL pattern ending with jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I have a Controller in Spring Boot application

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/vues/*.jsp")
    public String views(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return ((String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE)).substring(1);
    }

}
```

And in `application.properties`

```
server.context-path=/myapp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/myapp/
```

The goal is to dispatch all my jsp in the `WEB-INF/myapp/vues/` directory and **to keep the exact comportement of the older app with .jsp URL**

My app should work like this:

1. The user call `http://myapp/vues/page.jsp`
2. My app receive the call and find the handler in my controller because the URL match the RequestMapping url pattern
3. My handler return `vues/pages.jsp`
4. Spring Boot add `/WEB-INF/myapp/` to find the good JSP file

I've already developed several Spring Boot apps which work perfectly, with JSP and so on. But it seems in that case, that url pattern ending with JSP won't work.

I try in the same app with `@RequestMapping("/vues/*")`, `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` in application.properties and a call to the same url but without `.jsp` at the end and it work.

Is there a solution to configure Spring Boot to accept `*.jsp` by `RequestMapping`?

**NOTE:** I've seen lots of posts talking about this subject but none of them answer to this question

**UPDATE:** I continue to develop without the ending jsp, but in the code I cover, there are calls to `response.sendRedirect("../vues/view1");` or `request.getRequestDispatcher("../vues/view1.jsp")` and `request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/vues/view1.jsp");`. Everything seems a bit confusing. I know (beacause it was already done in the past!) is it posible to manage URL with ending `.jsp`. Why isn't this more popular? Why is it such a problem in springboot? Must I edit a `web.xml` file to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the default servlet in one class of configuration. You can do this by this way:

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc

```
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

}

After this you can use @RequestMapping("/some-mapping") without specifing the .jsp termination.

Comment: Sorry, but I need the exact opposite. My clients will call URL ending with .jsp. So I need @RequestMapping(".../.jsp") to work ; or at least I need my app to react when client call URL ending with .jsp